# Set up Default Upload path for uploading image in Joomla Default Editor

Tags: joomla-3.x, editor

I have 3 components related to newtoys, usedtoys and refurbishedtoys in which different article post and details been submitted

The Image folder has 3 subdirectories

1 image / newtoys

2 image / usedtoys

3 image / refurbishedtoys

Now whenever we try uploading a image through joomla default editor in backend - it always shows in /image folder and manually ask in to choose folder to upload image

As its cumbersome to check and manually select in folder to upload image

Is it possible that the editor in each of the component by default shows in the respective folder automatically to upload the image, without any manual intervention

For example the component of new toys - the media manager upload function should directly show in image / newtoys and save images in this directory, similar respective for other components too

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to go through the back-end of Joomla to populate the Media area. You can use FTP (or sftp) and simply transfer the files over that way. Or if you are using a CPANEL through the file manager. I'm using Joomla 3.6.0 and unless something has changed, what files in Media are not part of the MySQL database so you should be able to add files without going through Joomla.

In some hosting services, you can mount the account on your Desktop and then drag and drop the files to the Media area.

Comment: Its inconvenient to use FTP, point is if the media manager directly shows in uploaded path - it will be simple to upload image as part of content and the file will be automatically saved in respective directory folder

Comment: See if your web hosting service allows you to have your account's files appear on your Desktop. Then you could drag them over to the right directory and avoid uploading entirely. I do this on Joomla accounts all the time, and it can be easier than using the upload function.

Answer (score 1):

By default in Joomla! you can change the default path, but only for the main folder, in this case
 you can change this in:

- **System** > **Global Configuration** > **Media** > **Path to Images Folder**

You can solve this by using another editor, for example in [JCE Editor](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/edition/editors/jce) you can select a specific folder for each user, check more detailed information here:

- [Restricting users to a specific folder.](https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/tutorials/editor/setting-the-file-directory-path)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to override the admin views of different components you want different default upload folders for. E.g. to override the contacts admin view:

- copy /administrator/components/com_contacts/views/contact/tmpl/edit.php
- to administrator/templates/youradmintpl/html/com_contact/contact/edit.php
- Modify the copy of edit.php

  // Add this line:

  form->setFieldAttribute('image', 'directory', 'newtoys/'); ?>
  // before this: 
  form->renderField('image'); ?>

Now, when you click the image upload button, it will start inn the newtoys folder.